# Get product main and sub categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am creating a data scraper using scrapy python. I used this command to get categories but it show only one category

Link: https://royalprint.pk/product/name-print-superhero-sweatshirt-011/

```
In [6]: response.css('span.posted_in a::text').get() 
Out[6]: 'Name Print Sweatshirt'
```

Here is the Console preview

[image]

I want all Main and sub-categories in separate excel .csv columns

Please help.

Regards

Comment: please post the code as whole (to make it easy to reproduce it)

Comment: ive not used scrapy before only beautiful soup. have you tried getall() instead of get()?

Comment: Sir I have posted the shell code

Comment: @HjSin, by using getall i get this 

In [7]: response.css('span.posted_in a::text').getall()
Out[7]: ['Name Print Sweatshirt', 'Sweatshirts']

but is it possible to get product main category first and then sub category ? as woocommerce have Main Category > Sub category > Sub Sub Category

Comment: Just some tips: consider converting your css selectors to xpath, since scrapy automatically does it and you will gain performance when doing so + have the flexibility to traverse up and down (keywords: siblings, ancestor, descendant). Here you can find help with Xpath: https://css-selector-to-xpath.appspot.com/

Comment: with //span[@class='posted_in']/a I was able to select what I think you want in the browser inspect console (you can directly run xpath selects there in the search bar you open with command + F). so, I think response.xpath('//span[@class='posted_in']/a/text()').getall() might do the trick. See also here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html -> could not test it yet sadly

Comment: @HannahJames I hope the desired output is close enough for now, I am about to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Using the Scrapy Shell, I generated a simple spider with `scrapy genspider overflow <start_url>`.

You can run the spider with `scrapy runspider overflow.py`

```
import scrapy


class OverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'overflow'
    allowed_domains = ['royalprint.pk']
    start_urls = ['https://royalprint.pk/product/name-print-superhero-sweatshirt-011/']

def parse(self, response):
    categories=response.xpath("//span[@class='posted_in']/a/text()").getall()
    for category in categories:
        print(category)
```

It prints what you need.

If you want to save it, you can yield a dictionary (instead of the for loop):

```
yield dict.fromkeys(categories , ' ')
```

and define an output file, when you make the CLI call like so: `-o myOutput.csv`

Comment: @HannahJames just saw, that I missed you want an output in columns. This will output the categories in columns, but in the second row with the first row being ascending numbers. I guess you want the categories in 1st row, one per column?